# A mathematical function for denary to binary conversion.

Tags: functions

I an looking for the mathematical notation for a function that converts base 10 to base 2. The domain for the function should ideally be $\mathbb Z^+$, but a domain for one digit numbers would also be alright. I have tried using logarithms but I cannot understand how to create the binary string. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: decimal, not denary. And the function is clear: the number $A_1A_2\ldots A_n$ gets sent to $$A_12^{n-1}+A_22^{n-2}+\ldots+A_n$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all base 10 and base 2 are notations and not the integers themselves.  And integer will have a value no matter how it is written.  So if you want a *function* that converts base 10 to base two (a function being a mapping between two sets) then this is *not* a function on the integers but a function on *strings* of digits to another string of digits.

If you want a function from the integers themselves to a binary string (then it doesn't actually matter what notation the integer is notated in) there is no real *formula* for this but there are two recursive methods of doing this.

Method 1: Big to little.

Let $N$ but the natural number.  Let $n=\lfloor \log_2 N \rfloor$ (where $\lfloor . \rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal function).  Then the string will have $n+1$ terms and the "leftmost/largest" term is $a_n = 1$.  Let $N_{n}= N$.

Recursively for any $N_{m}$ and $a_m$ you have defined, define $N_{m-1}= N_m - a_m\cdot 2^m$.  If $N_{m-1}\ge 2^{m-1}$ define $a_{m-1}:=1$.  Otherwise define $a_{m-1}:=0$.

Repeat until you have figured out $a_0$.

For example to conver $364_{10}$ to binary.

As $2^8=256 < 364 < 2^9$ we know $8<\log_2 364 < 9$ so $n=\lfloor \log_2 364 \rfloor = 8$.  $N_8 = 364$ and $a_8 = 1$.

$N_7 = 364 - 2^8 =364-256 = 108$.  $108 < 128=2^7$ so $a_7=0$.

$N_6 = 108 - 0\cdot 2^7 = 108$.  $108 > 64 = 2^6$ so $a_6 = 1$.

$N_5 = 108 - 1\cdot 2^6=104-64=44$.  $44 > 32 = 2^5$ so $a_5 = 1$.

$N_4=40-1\cdot 2^5 = 40-32 = 12$.  $12 < 16 = 2^4$ so $a_4 = 0$.

$N_3 = 12 -0\cdot 2^4=12$.  $12 > 8 = 2^3$ so $a_3= 1$.

$N_2 = 12 - 1\cdot 2^3 =12 -8 =4$.  $4 \ge 4=2^2$ so $a_2 = 1$.

$N_1 = 4-1\cdot 2^2 =4-4=0$.  $0 < 2=2^1$ so $a_1 = 0$.

$N_0 = 0-0\cdot 2^1=0$.  $0 < 1 = 2^0$ so $a_0 = 0$.

So in binary $364_{10} = 101101100_2$.

Method 2: Little to big

Let $N = N_0$ be the natural number.  Let $a_0$ be the remainder of $N_0$ when divided by $2$.

For any known $N_m$ and $a_m$ let $N_{m+1} = \frac {N_m - a_m}2$. And let $a_{m+1}$ be the remainder of $N_{m+1}$ divided by $2$. Repeat until you come to a point where $N_m = 0$.

Example.  To convert $364_{10}$ to binary.

$N_0 = 364$.  The remainder when we divide by $2$ is $0$.  So $a_0 = 0$.

$N_1 = \frac {364-0}2 = 182$.  The remainder when we divide by $2$ is $0$. So $a_1 = 0$.

$N_2 = \frac {182-0}2 = 91$. The remainder when we divide by $2$ is $1$. So $a_2 = 1$.

$N_3 =\frac {91-1}2=45$.  The remainder when we divide by $2$ is $1$. So $a_3 = 1$.

$N_4 = \frac {45-1}2= 22$. The remainder when we divide by $2$ is $0$. So $a_4 = 0$.

$N_5 = \frac {22-0}2 =11$. The remainder when we divide by $2$ is $1$. So $a_5=1$.

$N_6 = \frac {11-1}2 =5$.  The remainder when we divide by $2$ is $1$. So $a_6=1$.

$N_7 = \frac {5-1}2=2$. The remainder when we divide by $2$ is $0$. So $a_7=0$.

$N_8 = \frac {2-0}2 = 1$. The remainder when we divide by $2$ is $1$. So $a_8=1$.

$N_9= \frac {1-1}2 = 0$.  We are done.

So in binary $364_{10} = 101101100_2$.

=====

A third method (which can be uncoil and poke you in the eye if you are not careful) is to note that $TEN = 2^3 + 2 = 1000_2 + 10_2$ and to know the single digit conversion.

Watch

$364_{10}= 3_{10}\times TEN^2 + 6_{10}\times TEN + 4_{10}=$

$3_{10}\times(1000_2 + 10_2)^2 + 6_{10}\times (1000_2+ 10_2) + 100_2=$

$(3_{10}\times 1000_2 + 3_{10}\times 10_2)(1000_2+10_2) + 110_2(1000_2 + 10_2) + 100_2=$

$(11,000 + 110)(1000+10) + 110,000 + 1,100 + 100 =$

$11,000,000 +110,000 + 110,000 + 1,100 + 110,000 + 1,100 + 100 =$

$11,000,000 + 110,000 + 110,000 + 1,000 + 110,000 + 1,000 + 100+100 + 100=$

$11,000,000 + 110,000 + 110,000 + 1,000 + 110,000 + 1,000 + 1,100=$

$11,000,000 + 110,000 + 110,000 + 110,000 + 1,000 + 1,000 + 1,000 + 100=$

$11,000,000 + 110,000 + 110,000 + 110,000 + 11,000 + 100=$

$11,000,000 + 110,000 + 110,000 + 110,000 + 10,000 + 1,100=$

$11,000,000 + 100,000 + 100,000 + 100,000 + 10,000 + 10,000 + 10,000 + 100,000 + 1,100=$

$11,000,000 + 1,100,000 + 1,000,000 + 1,100=$

$11,000,000 + 1,000,000 + 1,000,000 + 100,000 + 1,100=$

$11,000,000 + 10,000,000 + 101,100=$

$10,000,000 + 10,000,000 + 1,000,000 + 101,100=$

$100,000,000 + 1,101,100=$

$101,101,100_2$

Answer (score 2):

The mathematical function you seek does not have a special name, nor does it have a formula. If you search for [*decimal2binary*](https://www.google.com/search?q=decimal2binary) you will find algorithms for pen and paper calculation and coded in many languages.

You can give that function any name you like.

For single digits just use a table:

```
0    0
1    1
2   10
3   11
...
9 1001
```

Comment: @RobArthan Fixed thanks. You could have,